# Find $\theta(p)$ so that $\theta(\frac{n^2}{p})+\theta(n\log p)$ is minimal.

Tags: computational-complexity

> Find $\theta(p)$ so that $\theta\Big(\frac{n^2}{p}\Big)+\theta(n\log p)$ is minimal.

In my parallel programming class there was an algorithm that lead to a complexity of:
$$\theta\Big(\frac{n^2}{p}\Big)+\theta(n\log p)$$
Without any sort of an explanation it was said that the optimal complexity would be achieved if:
$$\theta(p)=\theta\Big(\frac{n}{\log n}\Big)$$
I fail to see why that's the case.
I can see that $\theta(p\log p)=\theta(n)$, however I am unable to make the transition to the answer.
Can any one here please help and show how to solve such problems?